# misplaced view warning in auto layout

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have a uiscrollview and content view inside it. I'm trying to use auto layout but when i set content view margins to its superview, it gives warning misplaced view, I have no idea what i'm doing wrong.
Is there any problem with navigation bar? because the difference is the exact height of navigation bar.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to update your frame.

Comment: @the_official_dahiya_boy if i update frame, scrollview would be y=64 and content view  y=0 but content view would be some where i don't want to.

Comment: Can you add our current UI. Because it updates according to your constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Simply Update Constraint from StoryBoard

[image]

It will automatically set your view as you have set.

Comment: I hope you will update Constraints from selected view

Comment: yes, i suppose it's about navigation bar. scroll view starts at y=64 and content view says its actual is y= -64 which is expected y=0

Comment: can you provide me code if possible I have try to solve it . bhumeshpurohit@ymail.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140053/discussion-between-bhumesh-purohit-and-hos-ap).

Answer (score 0):

Just click on that orange warning button and apply update frame, this will fix it. This warning is because of your view's bounds in xib are not satisfying with given constraints or given bound in left panel of view.

[image]